# Preferred ways to process JSON content

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to load **json** content from a CMS, and i will have to process the data in many ways. I am asking for good tools, best ways, *do-it-this-ways* to handle json data. I'm familiar with json, but not with my possibilities to handle it in an advanced way. Basically i load json content from an external site using jQuery ($ is already a dependency of my project), i need to

- validate the content if its valid json
- validate json if it contains some mandatory keys/fields
- remove/add/process values

If no better advice will be given, i will *validate the content* using `$.parseJSON`, and catch any upcoming exceptions. *Check if json contains* the mandatory fields using (PSEUDOCODE):

```
try 
  !json.hasKey(mandatory) throw exception
  !json.hasKey(otherMandatory) throw exception
catch exception
  missing key
```

and remove/add/process values as everyone would, because i don't know any better ways. So my question is, if there are any good habits, or tools to perform the former tasks on json datas?

Thanks!

Cheers

Comment: Consider _$.getJSON_ also: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: heikkim: i'm already using $.getJSON to get the content, but i'm not sure if this function checks validity 'good enough', so i want to re-check after success.